# While loop shows only one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this short code to echo two last lines from a MySql database. The problem is that it only shows one - the one but last - line. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am using almost the same code on another website where it works just fine. If I use LIMIT 1 in the Mysql query I get nothing to echo.
Could you help?
Thanks a lot.

```
<?
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT no, date, msg FROM news ORDER BY -no LIMIT 2");
   $data = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
   while ( $data = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
      $text = nl2br ( $data['msg'] );
      echo ('<b>Aktuality z Hlavatice ('.$data['date'].')</b><br /><br />' . $text);
   }
?>
```

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions! Use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 9):

Remove first `$data = mysql_fetch_array ($query);` and leave only that one in `while`.
This first call "steals" your first row and because of `LIMIT 2` you'll receive only one more.

Comment: Awsome. Thanks a lot. The question now is why it works in another script I'm using :)

Comment: @user2877941 Something have to be different in this another script. There is no other explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.... you are making mistake. remove $data = mysql_fetch_array ($query);

```
<?
$query = mysql_query("SELECT no, date, msg FROM news ORDER BY -no LIMIT 2");

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{   
$text = nl2br ($data['msg']);
echo ('<b>Aktuality z Hlavatice ('.$data['date'].')</b><br /><br />'.$text);
}
?>
```